# Edit a saved MATLAB figure using command line

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is there a way to reopen a saved MATLAB figure type file and edit it using commands in the command line, like one can do by generating a figure from the command line and make edits to it?

Thank you!

Comment: If you save it as a .fig file, `load`ing it puts you in the same place you were when you saved it. You should be able to continue modifying it as before.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
openfig('MySavedPlot.fig','visible')
```

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/openfig.html